# How to add tarball (Cardinality package) to dependency with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have mylib library package and myapp application. I want to use Cardinality package in mylib which is available only as tarball. So, I added to mylib stack.yaml:

```
packages:
  ...
  - location: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cardinality-0.2/Cardinality-0.2.tar.gz
    extra-dep: true
```

Then I add to mylib's cabal file:

```
build-depends: ...
               , Cardinality
```

And it's compilable. Now I'm trying to build myapp tool which depends on mylib:

```
packages:
  ...
  - '../mylib'
```

But I get error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for mylib:
    Cardinality must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest matching version is 0.2)
needed since mylib is a build target.

Some potential ways to resolve this:

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/XXXX/prj/myapp/stack.yaml:

- Cardinality-0.2

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * You may also want to try using the 'stack solver' command.

Plan construction failed.
```

So, how to add Cardinality tarball to mylib package in right way?!

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system, but it's possible you have something else going on in your `stack.yaml` that I can't see. Is there a specific reason you're referring to the URL explicitly instead of including `extra-deps: [Cardinality-0.2]`?

Comment: Hello, Michael!! As I understand, Cardinality is missing in Stackage, and I see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cardinality-0.2) that it's available only for NixOS and as tarball. So, I added dependency as "archive" with URL to tarball. I'll try it again tomorrow and will answer about result

Comment: Btw, I tried also "extra-deps" even with "@rev:0", but with the same error. OpenSuse, stack 1.6.3

Comment: Then my best guess is that there's something else in your `stack.yaml` file that's causing the problem, since it's working for me. Also: `extra-deps` is designed to work with packages on Hackage but not Stackage... Rereading your question: are you, by any chance, running `stack build` inside the `../mylib` directory, _away_ from your `stack.yaml` file?

Comment: No, I run `stack build` first: in mylib/ dir where is placed mylib's stack.yaml. Then I run `stack build` in dir of the application - where is placed stack.yaml of application. What I see is that stack tracks dependency Cardinality in mylib (!) and says that I need to add it as dependency in app's stack.yaml

Comment: may be the problem is in `packages:` section of app stack.yaml: how I define dependency `app <- mylib`? May be such dep. must be defined in other way?

Comment: [stack.yaml files of lib and app](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3742#issuecomment-355228049)

Comment: I added [attachment with 2 dummy projects](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3742#issuecomment-355252852) which shows the problem.

Comment: Michael Sloan already explained the problem in that issue: if you want to use a different stack.yaml in your app, you'll need to define the extra-dep in that stack.yaml too.

Comment: what does it mean "different stack.yaml"? What I can't understand is: if my libraries use some dependencies (let's suppose as "archive" tarballs) then all applications which use thos libraries should repeat "archive" dependencies in their own stack.yaml files? If it's true, this sounds cool.

Comment: Seems that I found solution: dependency between myapp and mylib should be defined as `extra-dep:` local FS path but not as `packages:`. So, IMO such problem must be refracted in some FAQ, guide, etc, because my use-case looks very usual

Comment: This workaround works for such simple projects, but does not work for complex projects with many "local" libraries. As for me, this is a bug in stack: what is "extra-deps:" in the case?! Dependencies of my dependencies (in extra-deps) must be re-included again?! If "extra-deps" is not real dependencies but some kind of "associated build job" or "include", so it should be named differently.

Comment: I don't have anything else to add to what I've said here and what Michael Sloan has already explained on Github.

Comment: @Paul-AG a start to documenting this would be if you posted your solution you found as an answer and accepted it, so people encountering this problem could see how you solved it without reading the comment history...